# MacOS - File Access Monitoring / Blocking

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

According to STIG guidelines for Mojave, it is essential to block access to certain paths, or audit the usage / require elevated permission dialogs of files running from certain paths.

I've already tried HandsOff, F-Secure, Managed Client Profiles, and Parental Controls - all are pretty inconsistent / dont accomplish the task.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you link to these guidelines? I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: Sure! Sorry wrong acronym :) 

Here's a link to the STIG Guidelines on macOS (jamf - Version: 1, Release: 2, 24 Jan 2020)

https://github.com/jamf/STIG-macOS-10_14/blob/master/README.md

If you look at AOSX_14_002067, under restrictions it describes:
Restrictions payload > Applications > Disallow "/Users"

In addition:
Restrictions payload > Applications > Disallow "/Applications/FaceTime.app"
Restrictions payload > Applications > Disallow "/Applications/Messages.app"

Apps can easily be blocked by renaming/moving - preventing access from folders seems to be a challenge.